# parametric method Autoregression moving average(ARMA) to AR process

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, moving-average

i want to know how to convert **ARMA (Autoregression moving average) process to AR(Autoregression) process by PARAMETRIC METHOD.**

i.e. i have a transfer function H(z) = (a + b*z)/(c +d*z) e.g. `H(z) = (0.26 + 0.073*z^-1)/(1 - z^-1)` i.e. Autoregression(ARMA)
and i want to convert it to AR process i.e. `H(z) = 1/(p + q*z + r*z^2 + ...)`(i.e only pole system).
Kindly Give some hints.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for partial partial fraction expansion commands, I suggest you try

```
[r, p, k] = residue(b,a)
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/residue.html

Comment: No its not partial fraction problem. Basically I need to convert a ARMA function(i.e. a pole and zero function ) to AR function( i.e. only Pole). In  this process Power spectrum density(PSD) of ARMA and AR are approx. same.